# C# Image.RotateFlip strange behaviour

Tags: c#

I'm using C# .Net Core 3.1 for some image manipulations on the backend.
Here I'm getting metadata about `source` image orientation and save correctly final rotated to `destination` image.
The strange thing here is if I run this code on Windows OS it works fine, but on the Linux OS it doesn't work.
Did someone face the same strange bug?

```
    private static void TransferImageOrientation(Image source, Image destination, string outpitPath = "")
    {
        try
        {
            if (source == null || destination == null) return;

            var imageOrientationProperty = source.PropertyItems
                .LastOrDefault(p => p.Id == (int) PropertyItemIds.PropertyTagOrientation || p.Id == (int) PropertyItemIds.ThumbnailOrientation);

            if (imageOrientationProperty == null) return;

            var imageOrientation = BitConverter.ToInt16(imageOrientationProperty.Value);
            var flipType = OrientationToFlipType(imageOrientation);

            destination.RotateFlip(flipType);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // ignored
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it failing to do the RotateFlip or is it failing to get a value for `imageOrientationProperty`?

Comment: The ignored Exception might tell you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Exception isnot thrown. imageOrientationProperty was received correctly both on Windows and Linux(tested before with logging).

Comment: When you say "It doesn't work", what happens? Is an error thrown? Does it not execute?